# Show that $\det(T_n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha^{n-k}\beta^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant

Let the matrix $T_n\in M(n\times n,\mathbb{F})$, where $\mathbb{F}$ denotes a field, be defined by $T_n=(t_{ij})$ with

$$t_{ij}= \begin{cases} 
      \alpha\beta &  1\leq i\leq n-1,\;j=i+1 \\
      \alpha+\beta & 1\leq i\leq n,\; j=i \\
      1 & 2\leq i\leq n,\; j=i-1 \\
      0 &\textrm{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$

Show that 
$$\det(T_n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha^{n-k}\beta^k$$

---

**My approach:** I tried a proof via induction and while the basis step is trivial, I can't seem to solve the induction step since the matrix is never in upper or lower triangular form but always a block matrix, which makes this seemingly difficult as when calculating the determinant of block matrices, one usually calculates the product of all the "diagonal blocks".

I would very much appreciate help, thank you very much.

Comment: I think you get a recurrence relation by expanding by first column, and then expanding the second term by the first row.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/383735/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2216162/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2262488/42969.

Comment: Have you seen your determinant: $$\begin{vmatrix}\alpha+\beta&\alpha\beta&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\1&\alpha+\beta&\alpha\beta&0&\ldots&0&0\\0&1&\alpha+\beta&\alpha\beta&\ldots&0&0\\0&0&1&\alpha+\beta&\ldots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&\alpha+\beta&\alpha\beta\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&1&\alpha\beta\end{vmatrix}$$?

Comment: Thanks that really is the same matrix but the identity they have to prove looks different.

Comment: @user: The lower right entry in your matrix is $\alpha + \beta$, isn't it? So that is not quite the same matrix. – But note that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha^{n-k}\beta^k = \frac{\alpha^{n+1} - \beta^{n+1}}{\alpha - \beta}$  for $\alpha \ne \beta$, so the solutions in the above referenced Q&As are exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that's true thanks, but where did you get that identity? This doesn't look like we can simply apply the geometric series formula.

Comment: @user:  What happens if you multiply $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha^{n-k}\beta^k$ with $(\alpha  - \beta)$? Can you see how all terms cancel, with the exception of $\alpha^{n+1} - \beta^{n+1}$? – See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2476730/42969.

Comment: @MartinR All right thank you very much, now I see it.